# What is the efficiency of dividing N positive integers by a given power of 2?

Tags: algorithm, performance, bit-shift

For example:

Let's say `N = 128`.
We want to divide each positive integer up to and including `N`, by say, `8`.
So we would perform integer division for:

```
1/8
2/8
3/8
...
127/8
128/8
```

In looking this up, I see that bit shift operations are the way to go and that any good compiler will automatically do it that way in the first place. But nonetheless, I can't seem to find any big O function for this type of algorithm.

To sum up: given a positive integer `N`, and a number `Y` which is a power of `2`, what is the efficiency of an algorithm which divides each of the numbers `1,2,3,...,N` by `Y`?

Comment: Dividing N integers by a scalar number should have run-time complexity of O(N). Bit-shifting is a smaller complexity than iterating over all the numbers

Comment: Most modern processors will take the same amount of time to shift by `Y` places regardless of how big or small `Y` is.

Comment: I'd call anything not conditional trivial, if algorithm at all.

Comment: @greybeard What if there was a conditional after each division?  So say same "algorithm" as above, but after each division we check if the resulting integer is even or odd.

Comment: Why is there a conditional? Those divisions are done in a single right shift instruction

Comment: There is no conditional. The OP is me trying to understand how efficiency these "right shift instructions" are (forgive me, if that's a stupid/trivial question). And then in these comments I appended that to suppose that after each division there _was_ some conditional....giving an example of determining if the resulting integer was even or odd

Comment: Do you actually need to divide or bit-shift? Given that `Y` is a power of 2, `!(N & Y)` would produce a boolean that is true if even. Use another `!` to get true if odd. In some languages, you can even skip the `!`s as zero and non-zero are equivalent to false and true.

Comment: The actual bit-shift is likely to be faster than you can pull the operands out of memory, unless it's already in L1 cache.

Comment: ((In the RAM model,) Each division/shift is bound to take constant time. There are `N` steps like this, so the time complexity is bounded above by `c1*N³logN`, even `c2*N²` or `c0*N`, so the function describing it is of the order of (or in, as some prefer) _O(N³logN)_ as well as _O(N)_. If you wanted, say, the values from 1/Y to N/Y, you don't need to divide: start with a quotient and remainder 0. For each further quotient, increment the remainder; if it reaches Y, increment the quotient and zero the remainder. _Θ(N)_ (and _O(N)_, accordingly).)